# error when trying to connect to server for next the connection using sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I am learning socket programming using python. my first assignment is to a write a client.py and a server.py. The `client` sends a message to `server`.   The `server` receives the message of `16 bytes` each time. After it has received the entire message, it will send the same message back to `client`.
so it is very simple. The server has backlog of 1. After the server sends the message to client, the connection to client close and the server should be open to receive new connection.
my current code fails in the last step. It is not open to receive new connections. It is throwing error. I even figured out the error. but I do not know how to fix this.

The error comes from server.py because I call for `sock.accept()` but I have closed the `sock`. 
Let me explain my server.py code: I have two `while loops`. The `outer loop` looks for new connection, and the `inner loop` looks process request from connections i.e it simply receives data, wait till everything is received and send it back to client and finally close the connection.

I am asked not to change the structure of two `while loops` but just implement them.
Any thoughts or ideas on this:

`client.py`

```
import socket
import sys


def client(msg, log_buffer=sys.stderr):
    server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    print >>log_buffer, 'connecting to {0} port {1}'.format(*server_address)
    try:
        print >>log_buffer, 'sending "{0}"'.format(msg)
        sock.sendall(msg)
        chunk = ''
        done=False;
        while not done:
            chunk+=sock.recv(16)
            if chunk==msg:
                done=True

        print >>log_buffer, 'received "{0}"'.format(chunk)
    finally:
        print >>log_buffer, 'closing socket'
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        usg = '\nusage: python echo_client.py "this is my message"\n'
        print >>sys.stderr, usg
        sys.exit(1)

    msg = sys.argv[1]
    client(msg)
```

`Server.py`

```
import socket
import sys


def server(log_buffer=sys.stderr):
    # set an address for our server
    address = ('127.0.0.1', 10000)
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)


    # log that we are building a server
    print >>log_buffer, "making a server on {0}:{1}".format(*address)

    sock.bind(address)
    sock.listen(1)

    try:
        # the outer loop controls the creation of new connection sockets. The
        # server will handle each incoming connection one at a time.
        while True:
            print >>log_buffer, 'waiting for a connection'

            conn,add=sock.accept()
            addr=(conn,add)
            try:
                print >>log_buffer, 'connection - {0}:{1}'.format(*addr)

                # the inner loop will receive messages sent by the client in 
                # buffers.  When a complete message has been received, the 
                # loop will exit
                data = ''
                while True:

                    recvdata=conn.recv(16)
                    print recvdata
                    data+=recvdata
                    print >>log_buffer, 'received "{0}"'.format(data)
                    print >>log_buffer, "len of received data: {0}".format(len(recvdata))
                    if len(recvdata)<16:
                        print >>log_buffer,"sending data"
                        conn.sendall(data)
                        break
                conn.close()


            finally:

                sock.close()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
    sys.exit(0)
```

I run`python server.py in one terminal and`python client.py "This is the first message. send me back"` in a different terminal. The client connection is lost normally as expected. But I get the following error at server side (towards the end):

```
making a server on 127.0.0.1:10000
waiting for a connection
connection - <socket._socketobject object at 0x100849c20>:('127.0.0.1', 50626)
sairam hopefully
received "sairam hopefully"
len of received data: 16
 this works lets
received "sairam hopefully this works lets"
len of received data: 16
 c
received "sairam hopefully this works lets c"
len of received data: 2
sending data
waiting for a connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "echo_server.py", line 89, in <module>
    server()
  File "echo_server.py", line 39, in server
    conn,add=sock.accept()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing `sock` inside your while loop. Don't do that. `sock` is your long-lasting server socket, which needs to remain open to listen for new connections. `conn` is your ephemeral socket, which needs to remain open only the length of a single connection.

Close `conn` after each connection, close `sock` when the server needs to terminate.

More simply, replace these lines:

```
       finally:
            sock.close()
```

with

```
       finally:
            conn.close()
```

Comment: yes, I thought so. but the instruction for  me said `# TODO: When the inner loop exits, this 'finally' clause will
                #       be hit. Use that opportunity to close the socket you
                #       created above when a client connected.  Replace the
                #       call to `pass` below, which is only there to prevent 
                #       syntax problems`

Comment: In that case, replace `sock.close()` with `conn.close()`. They key is in the instruction: "*close the socket you created above **when a client connected***". In your case, that's `conn`, not `sock`.

Comment: That fixed but I now get `socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use` although I have `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)`  to re-use address?

Comment: That's a new question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a simple echo server, which I believe you can implement much more simply.

Server:

```
import socket 

host = '' 
port = 50000 
backlog = 5 
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog) 
while 1: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size) 
    if data: 
        client.send(data) 
    client.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket 

host = 'localhost' 
port = 50000 
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((host,port)) 
s.send('Hello, world') 
data = s.recv(size) 
s.close() 
print 'Received:', data
```